# Terraform plan unsupported block type "http_endpoint_configuration"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to send my CloudWatch logs to DataDog, for this purpose I am trying to use `aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream` as stated in:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream

This is my code snippet:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "CAIWH-kinesis-firehose-datadog" {
  bucket = "fswh-kinesis-firehose-datadog-${var.env}"
}

resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "test_stream_caiwh" {
  name        = "terraform-kinesis-firehose-captainai-test-stream"
  destination = "http_endpoint"

  s3_configuration {
    role_arn           = aws_iam_role.CAIWH-datadog_firehose.arn
    bucket_arn         = aws_s3_bucket.CAIWH-kinesis-firehose-datadog.arn
    buffer_size        = 10
    buffer_interval    = 400
    compression_format = "GZIP"
  }

  http_endpoint_configuration {
    url                = "https://aws-kinesis-http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com/v1/input"
    name               = "DataDogSecond"
    access_key         = var.datadog_api_key
    buffering_size     = 15
    buffering_interval = 600
    role_arn           = aws_iam_role.CAIWH-datadog_firehose.arn
    s3_backup_mode     = "FailedDataOnly"

    request_configuration {
      content_encoding = "GZIP"

      common_attributes {
        name  = "testname"
        value = "testvalue"
      }

      common_attributes {
        name  = "testname2"
        value = "testvalue2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I constatly get the following error:
Error: Unsupported block type

```
  on datadog.tf line 87, in resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "test_stream_caiwh":
  87:   http_endpoint_configuration {
Blocks of type "http_endpoint_configuration" are not expected here.
```

Tried updating my Terraform version but without success, my current version is `Terraform v0.13.6`

Comment: What is your aws provider version? Try with source = "hashicorp/aws"; version = "4.19.0"

Comment: version = "~> 3.0" for provider "aws" did the trick for me, but thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

use version = "~> 5.0" for provider "aws"